# Can I use ARCGIS SERVER non-pooled services In arcgis server silverlight api?

Tags: silverlight, arcgis, arcgis-server

I am using arcgis server silverlight api3.0

I need to Use some non-pooled Arcgis server 10I services.  Can somebody explain me Is it possible or not?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Nonpooled services are not available at 10.1. Please see follow ArcGIS Help of "Migrating services" section.

[Migration to ArcGIS 10.1 for Server](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//0154000002p0000000)